# Should I hang drywall up to the ceiling (using steel studs)?

Tags: drywall

If my studs are 3 meter high, will I have any problems if I hang drywall up to 2.4 meters, leaving 0.6 meter of stud showing? Or should the drywall cover all the studs?

PS: I'm using steel studs.

Comment: What type of space are you talking about?

Comment: No space in particular, just curious if this could pose a problem. I ask that because I will have drywall ceiling that is lower that the height of the beams.

Comment: Is this a temporary thing until you install the ceiling?  What kind of problems are you worried about?

Comment: I'm not saying  I'm gonna do that. I was just curious if this was ok since I couldn't find the info elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drywall is part of the fire retardation system in many types of construction. The thickness is specifically designated to provide a certain timing before a fire can spread to an adjoining area.

Failing to have the drywall fully enclose the wall defeats this. It also compromises the insulation of the room, both with regard to temperature and sound. It may also increase the likelihood of air infiltration (drafts and temperature issues).

If this is just temporary (as @TheEvilGreebo queries), you may be fine so long as an inspection is not done and you will seal up the space soon.

If this is a permanent approach, you have a problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is just about code. Everything I've read says that when you're using metal studs, full drywall is a part of the structural element. Unless you have all (or most of) the studs stabilized by the drywall, isn't OP introducing an element of danger?

Comment: I agree, I understand now it is a bad idea. I was just wondering because in my house I will have about 30 cm of wall above the ceiling (between ceiling and top slab) that is "unused".